# adding DNS entry (ex. server.domain.com) to domain controller

Tags: windows, dns

I have a server that I have assigned an external IP address to it and NAT'd through in my firewall.  Then I have assigned with my domain host provider and made a DNS name to point to that external.   All is great from the outside, and inside if I point to the local IP address of that server.

My problem is that the software that is on the server I cannot access certain Java features outside of the network because the local IP address is hardcoded into the software and Java wont read both internal and external IP address.  So tech support on the software said we can put in a DNS name into the software.

So I went into the DNS of my domain controller and put in an Host (A) entry of subdomain.domain.com and the local IP address.  Well it doesnt resolve right because DNS made the entry I put in as subdomain.domain.com.local so again Java doesn't read it right.  How do I make DNS read this entry right as subdomain.domain.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this a windows DNS solution and domain controller?  if so, the A record should just be "subdomain" (windows will add on domain.com since that is the domain for the domain controller).  If this is the case, try that A record, and it should work.

**UPDATE**

Based on comments below, it sounds like you need to do this:

Create a new zone using your external domain name.

1. Open DNS console.
2. Click on Forward Lookup Zones.
3. Right-click, choose new Zone, type in the name of the external
   domain name (srb1.com).
4. Once created, right-click the zone you just created, choose New Host
   Record.
5. Type in 'software' (without the quotes), and provide the internal Private
   IP address of your internal webserver.

These instructions were pulled from here:  [Scenario 2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/26da4868-e548-4f84-976e-762d908bde23/how-do-you-manage-different-internal-and-external-domain-names)

Comment: Yes sorry windows server 2003

Comment: my current domain is ndw.local

Comment: What is the reason you can't just point to the external IP address of the server from your software configuration?  Internal and external network should be able to see that IP...

Comment: Finally, if it must be subdomain.domain.com that points to external IP, this needs to be configured in the DNS that manages domain.com, not the DNS that manages ndw.local.

Comment: I guess I should give a better example.  It is software.srb1.com is what I can go to to get to my servers website from outside the network.  When I add that to a DNS entry inside my network to point to the local address it makes it software.srb1.com.ndw.local, which Java throws a fit with because we have hardcoded into the software as software.srb1.com.  If I put the external IP address into the software configuration you cannot access the Java features from the internal as we connect to it with the internal address.

Comment: So is your internal domain (ndw.local) disconnected from getting out to the external domain (i.e. you can't hit google.com from the ndw.local network)?

Comment: No I can get out to the outside world.  But if I type software.srb1.com I cannot get there because that server is in my local network and I cannot go to one of my external IP addresses from inside my network.